# How to ensure FormData is instantiated AFTER bootstrap has changed a radio input 'checked' status

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, form-data

I'm trying to send some `FormData` via an `XMLHttpRequest` when a `click` event is detected on the `<label>` encasing a `<input type="radio" name="myName" id="myRadio" value="myValue">`:

```
let labels = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("myLabels"));
labels.forEach( (label) => {
    label.addEventListener("click", () => {
        //toggle label class to change css, then...
        let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));
        //ajax stuff now...
```

[The fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/zav9brcs/1/)

The trouble is that I already have instantiated the `new FormData` before bootstrap's js gets around to setting `#myRadio.checked` after the label was clicked, and so the `FormData` has the wrong value for `myName` (it's got the value of the previously-active label's underlying radio input, not the currently active label's input).

Detecting a change in `#myRadio.checked` isn't possible without recording some sort of state - the `checked` status is set by clicking a label in bootstrap, so the actual DOM `checked="true"` attribute isn't set.

Coping with this by introducing a timeout here seems like a hack. How do I get the right data in my `FormData`?

For reference, [here's the bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) on radios styled as buttons. I don't see any inbuilt ways to tell when a method is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT] updated code (now using jQuery to ease things)
and [the Fiddle you requested](https://jsfiddle.net/arhak/zzzcx8hc/1/)

```js
$('label.btn').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).children('input').val());
  // first uncheck them all
  $('label.btn input').prop('checked', false)
    // notice how classes are in the parent of the input
    .parent().addClass('btn-secondary').removeClass('btn-primary').removeClass('active');
  // then check our child
  $(this).children('input').prop('checked', true)
    // notice how classes are in the parent of the input
    .parent().addClass('btn-primary active').removeClass('btn-secondary');
  // then the FormData
  let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));
  for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair);
  }
});

/*
$('label.btn').on('click', function() {
  // click on the label is not the same as click on the input
  console.log($('input[name="preview"]:checked').val() + " is checked" );
});
*/
```

```html
<head>
<!-- 
Bootstrap dependencies:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start
-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>

<form id="myForm">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="preview" id="preview-enabled" value="Alice" autocomplete="off" checked>Alice
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="preview" id="preview-disabled" value="Bob" autocomplete="off">Bob
  </label>
</div>
</form>

</body>
```

===

First answer attempt was:

<strike>in the following example you can find some corrections, nevertheless notice that the strange behavior is due to the checked status at the time of the click event (which doesn't change until the event is over)</strike>

```
let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="preview"]');
console.log(nodes);

[].slice.call(nodes).forEach( (node) => {
    node.parentNode.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(node);
        console.log(node.parentNode.className);
        console.log(jQuery('input[name="preview"]:checked').val()) + ' is checked';
        if(node.checked === true){
            node.parentNode.className = node.parentNode.className.replace('btn-secondary', 'btn-primary' );
        } else {
            node.parentNode.className = node.parentNode.className.replace('btn-primary', 'btn-secondary' );
        }
        let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));
        for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(pair);
        }
    }); //end eventListener function
});
```

Comment: Yes, as I said; the bootstrap js changes the input *after* the event - so what's the solution to getting the correct FormData without a timeout?

Comment: @Escher sorry, now I got the idea. See my updated answer. Notice that click on labels is not the same as click on radio (input) which are actually children of he labels, therefore you should be careful regarding what you're addressing (BTW new code uses jQuery to make it easier)